# Union columns from different tables

Tags: sqlite

Assuming I have 2 tables:
`Persons: ID, Name`
`Pets: PName`

I want to select all the IDs from `Persons` and assign each one with a different `PName` or NULL if there are more IDs.
Basically it looks like a simple `select` query from `Persons` and then somehow append a `select` query from `Pets` but I'm not sure how to do that.  I tried to use `JOIN` and `UNION` but none of them gave me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How is the pet name related to a person? I do not see a relation. It is just a table with names. You would want to add an ID to your pets table and probably a foreign key to the person.

Comment: It's not. I won't waste your time with the reasons for this query, I just want to know if there is a way I'll get a result like:    
1, Dog; 2, Cat; 3, NULL; 4, NULL

Comment: You join data from different tables by a relationship between that data. If there is no relation between them, you can't combine those tables the way you want.

Comment: Thanks @LarsRotgers, I'll do it a different way

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary tables for IDs and names:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1(ID) AS SELECT ID FROM Persons;
CREATE TEMP TABLE t2(PName) AS SELECT PName FROM Pets;
```

Then use the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) to join them:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.PName
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.rowid = t2.rowid;
```